How to acheive a user specific password policy in keycloak
In my particular realms i wanted to create a user who's password doesn't expire for a long period of time , but by default in keycloak uses the realm password policy for all user.
Is there a way we can acheive this implementing any adaptor interface in keycloak.

You can implement a custom PasswordPolicyProviderFactory with a PasswordPolicyProvider that validates based on the UserModel and configure this for the realm.
